# Using Trinidad in JSF environment

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

I'm facing an unpleasant issue with an JSF based application of mine.
Right now i have several xhtml-Files which include / make use the following 
taglibs:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

Now I want to include apache trinidad too because I need it's dialog functionality
and so I added

```
xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
```

to the namespaces, the jars and the trinidad-config.xml to the web-inf folder.

In order to see whether the lib is available I've inserted

```
 <tr:outputText value="someString"/>
```

into the relevant xhtml file. The actual issue is, that the outputText gets
not rendered in the UI. No error message, nothing in the apache logs, it just
does'nt render...

Does anyone's got an idea where to start resolving this?

EDIT:

2romaintaz: I have'nt touched the web.xml yet, might that be the problem source?

TIA

K

Comment: It will be helpfull to see your web.xml file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/installation.html), you need to modify your configuration in order to enable Trinidad on your JSF application:

- web.xml must define `filter` and `filter-mapping` as well as `servlet` and `servlet-mapping`.
- faces-config.xml must define the render-kit.

Comment: using jsf2.0 I don't need to have faces-config, so am wondering why still not working for me even after I added the filter and servlet?